# Why doesnt setInterval excute a function defined before it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Why doesn't the following JavaScript function as expected?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function sayHello(){alert("Hello");}
  setInterval('sayHello()', 1000);
});
```

Comment: To be clear, the reason this works in some instances and not in this one is because you are defining `sayHello` inside of the anonymous function, and when `setInterval` is passed a string it will `eval` that string in global context, losing its association with the anonymous function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change ur code!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function sayHello(){alert("Hello");}
  setInterval(sayHello, 1000);
});
```

that should work ^_^

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/hmRpS/

Comment: Thanks Neal!, when are parenthesis necessary?

Comment: @Babiker the paren are ness when u have params in the function ^_^

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(sayHello, 1000);  .
```

Answer (score 1):

My first glance is this:

```
setInterval(sayHello, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the function is local to the `ready` function.

Make it global and it will work:

```
function sayHello() {
   alert("Hello");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function() {
      sayHello();
   }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason the original code doesn't work is that because you're passing a string to setInterval, it must eval() it to execute the code. However, by the time setInterval is ready to call the code, the function has gone out of scope (since it's only defined within the ready event handler,) and so nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Short in depth explanation.

`setInterval( STRING , NUMBER )` uses `eval` to interpret the string and this `eval` is executed in the global scope and not the function scope, since the nature of a timeout makes it drop out of any function scope.

`sayHello` resides inside a function and as such, is not present in the global scope.

Ergo the `setInterval( STRING , NUMBER )` will throw a missing object error in the given example.

`setInterval( FUNCTION , NUMBER )` makes sure the timeout uses a reference/pointer and avoids the need to do a global `eval`.